# Drawing text with a table to a PDF in Quartz

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I'm trying to draw a report to a PDFContext in Quartz.  The template is in MS Word.  I was wondering if there was advice on how to do a table.  Like if this was a table with outlines:

### column heading 1 | col heading 2 | col heading 3 | col 4

### row 1 col 1 | row 1 col 2| row 1 col 3| row 1 col 4|

row 2, etc

I wasn't sure how hard this was to do in Quartz and what the best method to do this was.  Thanks.

Or if this is somehow doable in UIKit, I'm fine with that too.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is doable using UIKit, you can draw a pdf. [Check this out](http://www.ioslearner.com/generate-pdf-programmatically-iphoneipad/). All you have to do is draw a text, then a line, and repeat the process. This seems to be a heading and i think, would have data under each row and column. Probably, make a generic function, may be a for loop, that will automate the process.